# Hibernate Criteria order by a specific state

Tags: hibernate, criteria, formula

Hi
In the database, we have a PRSN_ADDRESS table which has many addresses. A user is shown these addresses in a grid. The requirement is show the addresses associated with this user's state first and then show all other states.

For example, say the table has 10 records with 5 of the addresses having state as Maryland, 2 from PA and 3 from NJ. Now if the user is associated with Maryland, we need to show all the 10 addresses, but Maryland addresses should show up in the first five and then the other 5 in any order.

We are using Hibernate Criteria. I haven't worked on Formulas and not sure if that would help solve the problem. It would be great if anyone can point me in the right direction. I appreciate that.

Thanks

Harish

Answer (score 5):

You can order by a conditional value...

(NHibernate way, anyone know the equivalent in Hibernate?)

```
.AddOrder(Order.Asc(
    Projections.Conditional(
         Restrictions.EqProperty("addr.state", "user.state"), Projections.Constant(0), Projections.Constant(1))))
.AddOrder(Order.Asc("addr.state"))
```

translates to...

```
order by 
    case when addr.state = user.state then 0 else 1 end,
    addr.state
```

Comment: Joe, thank you for your reply, but I get a compiler error on Projections.Constant. Is that right?

Comment: Also I'm using Java & Hibernate and not nHibernate. So Projections.Conditional & Projections.Constant give compiler error on eclipse. Is there an equivalent on Hibernare

Comment: ya this is for NHiberante...I'm not sure what it is called in Hibernate.

Comment: and my google skills on hibernate api are coming up blank...surely there is something similar?

Comment: Thanks Joe. Your SQL works great, but I'm not able to get the Hibernate equivalent :(. Can someone help on this please :)

Comment: just been trying to do this in hibernate. It doesn't look like it's possible using the Criteria API, It is possible (I think) via HQL

Comment: Gareth...Can you please provide a sample code for HQL, I haven't used it yet, but then I can change from criteria to HQL. Appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: @dotjoe Yes, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359060/criteria-use-aggregate-function-in-order-by-clause/17361164#17361164

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure the there is a really cleaver way todo this but my initial thought is just to do two queries. First with the `state == 'Maryland'` and second `state != 'Maryland'`. And stitch the results together your self.

It is possible using HQL:

```
from Person p order by case when p.addr.state = 'Maryland' then '0' else '1' end asc, p.addr.state asc
```

I've prepared an example over on github

https://github.com/gid79/q4510810-hibernate-criteria-order-by-a-specific-state

Comment: Thanks so much Gareth. I'm still trying to get a solution using Criteria API. If that doesn't work out I would change to HQL as I haven't used HQL in the past and it involves a lot of changes to the existing code. Appreciate it.

Comment: In that case the simplest possible solution is just to do two queries, the feature will be done in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Harish, 
    If I understand it right, all you will have to do is add order to the criteria.
`List addresses = sess.createCriteria(PRSN_ADDRESS.class)
    .addOrder( Order.asc(user.state) )
    .list();`

Comment: This won't put the user's state as the top results though. It will merely put the user's states in alphabetical order.