# JPA Criteria query order by enum values

Tags: jpa, enums, sql-order-by, case, criteria-api

How to sort enums with JPA criteria. 
For example to get a query like 
"ORDER BY CASE color WHEN 'YELLOW' THEN 1 WHEN 'RED' THEN 3 ELSE 2 END"

Comment: I think it is not possible with JPQL, but you could use JPA NativeQuery.

Comment: I guess since JPQL support case-when in order-by clause, the JPA Criteria API also should support it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you just need to wrap the case expression with an asc or desc.

What code have you tried, and what error do you get?

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Order

Comment: But where do we specify which column to order by?

Comment: I just want to know if there is some API in JPA Criteria like the one specified in [Hibernate Criteria order by a specific state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510810/hibernate-criteria-order-by-a-specific-state)

Answer (score 0):

The Case Expressions in JPA Criteria API can solve the problem.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()

cb.selectCase(color)
.when(color.YELLOW, 1)
.when(color.YELLOW, 2)
.otherwise(3))
```

Comment: But now I get the error:-    java.lang.ClassCastException: color cannot be cast to org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.Renderable at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.SimpleCaseExpression.render(SimpleCaseExpression.java:146) at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.SimpleCaseExpression.renderProjection(SimpleCaseExpression.java:157) at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.CompoundSelectionImpl.render(CompoundSelectionImpl.java:99) at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.CompoundSelectionImpl.renderProjection(CompoundSelectionImpl.java:110) at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.QueryStructure.rende

Comment: See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6747 - it is a known, but ignored bug. Works with eclipselink, which also has annoying simple bugs related to case expressions :). 

Try 
`cb.selectCase()
  .when(cb.equals(color, color.YELLOW), 1)
  .when(cb.equals(color, color.RED), 3)
  .otherwise(2)`

Comment: Just tested the workaround, it does not work due to bug https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4700, which is three years old, so maybe the only possibility is to patch hibernate yourself or go for other JPA provider :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle it after reading JPA Docs:http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Order
I didn't go deep how it handles internally but I guess it sort based on enum ordinals

```
 criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(Root.get("columnName")));
```