# Criteria use aggregate function in order by clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one criteria and i stuck with following:

I am using sql server so in my sql server I have following condition(Note: I am not putting whole query here I am just putting my order by clause)

```
order by (IIF(LEN(Code) = 1, '0'+Code ,Code))
```

**"Code"** is my column name, Now I want to implement same in hibernate in following

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("CTC.code"));
```

Please help me out to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After spending too much time and googling I found working solution from here:

http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/

In that example they have override Order class's method of criteria, I got what i was wanted, really charm for me.

Comment: Please do not add link-only answers. When the link is broken, nobody know how to solve the problem anymore.